# How exploitable is a none JWT?

Tags: authentication, jwt

A recent penetration test has discovered that my org is using the JWT authentication scheme that allows the 'none' algorithm. How exploitable is this in the real world?

I understand that the issue can be used by an attacker to change the payload to another user and then 'sign' it using the none algorithm that would be accepted, however the only real payload information that could be enumerated is the subject and a random value.

Would an attacker be able to brute force the subject field and gain access to another person's account? How realistic is this?

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "the subject and a random value"? Subject of what? And what is the random value used for?

Comment: You didn't give us enough information to properly answer your question. But there are multiple things to worry about. Obviously your application doesn't just take the whole JWT and use it like a session ID, so that's off the table. But the attacker could for instance use the payload to perform unexpected injection-attacks. Or they could change the expiration date of the JWT. There are MANY things that can go wrong, if the signature doesn't get verified properly, since applications typically rely on it.

Comment: The "none" algorithm means "There is no signature". Any claim is trusted. Always.

Answer (score 1):

There's two aspects to your question:

- Is a JWT token exploitable if it can be signed with the "none" algorithm?

Absolutely, yes.

- Does it matter in your specific case where only a certain type of information is handled by the token that you know to be safe if tampered with?

Entirely up to you. This is the context that weighs the business risk of a particular issue.

From a development point of view, I suggest you disable the "none" signature algorithm and save yourself headaches and potential compromise when in the future you use the JWT token in a slightly different way and forget about this issue.

Here's a couple of resources:

- https://auth0.com/blog/critical-vulnerabilities-in-json-web-token-libraries/
- https://medium.com/101-writeups/hacking-json-web-token-jwt-233fe6c862e6